# CS1061: 'Bookmarks' does not contain a definition for 'Item'

Tags: c#, .net, forms, ms-word

I am trying to program a app for chain letters.

This is my Template: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/troubleshoot/office-developer/automate-word-create-file-using-visual-c

This is my code: https://github.com/440z/2021-07-01_WindowsFormsAppFuerKettenBriefMitWord

**The error occurs  in file Form1.cs in line 171.**

```cs
Word._Document oDoc;
// ...
object oBookMark = "MyBookmark";
oDoc.Bookmarks.Item(ref oBookMark).Range.Text = "Some Text Here"; // L171
```

error CS1061: 'Bookmarks' does not contain a definition for 'Item' and no accessible extension method 'Item' accepting a first argument of type 'Bookmarks' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I set a using directive and made a assembly reference how described in the template.

---

Add a reference to Microsoft Word Object Library. To do this, follow these steps:
On the Project menu, click Add Reference.
On the COM tab, locate Microsoft Word Object Library, and then click Select.

and

using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

using System.Reflection;

---

I just don't get it!!!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [ask]. In particular, please make sure your question contains all of the information required to understand it. People aren't going to go and click through an entire project on GitHub just to understand what's wrong, instead your question should include a small [mcve]. Please [edit] your question to meet the guidelines, otherwise you probably won't get any answers, and you'll likely be downvoted and/or closed

Comment: From a quick glance: did you mean to write `Bookmarks.get_Item(ref oBookMark)` instead of `Bookmarks.Item(ref oBookMark)`?

Comment: is this an indexer? i.e. `oDoc.Bookmarks[ref oBookMark]...`? (with or without the `ref`, whatever compiles) - edit: looks like it might be: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.bookmarks.item?view=word-pia#Microsoft_Office_Interop_Word_Bookmarks_Item_System_Object__

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `Bookmarks` has an *indexer*, so: try one of

```cs
oDoc.Bookmark[ref oBookMark].Range.Text = "Some Text Here";
```

or

```cs
oDoc.Bookmark[oBookMark].Range.Text = "Some Text Here";
```

However, I would *expect* this to *now* complain that you're trying to access an invalid key, meaning: there is no existing bookmark keyed by `"MyBookmark"`

Comment: @HisDudeness you should be able to do that in place of all of the `get_Item` usages